# Converting shell script to Ansible play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to translate a shell script into Ansible.

Snippet of code that is confusing me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql mssql-tools 
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

What I have so far:

```
- name: Install SQL Server prerequisites
  apt: name={{item}} state=present
  update_cache: yes
  with_items:
  - msodbcsql
  - mssql-tools
  - unixodbc-dev
```

No idea where to tie in `ACCEPT_EULA=Y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an environment variable, so:

```
- name: Install SQL Server prerequisites
  apt:
    name: "{{item}}"
    state: present
    update_cache: yes
  with_items:
    - msodbcsql
    - mssql-tools
    - unixodbc-dev
  environment:
    ACCEPT_EULA: Y
```

And mind the indentation. It's really important in YAML.